# How to convert JSON to object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
{
    "mon" : {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 2,
        "c" : 4
    }
    "tue" : {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 2,
        "c" : 4
    }
    "wed" : {
        "a" : 3,
        "b" : 2,
        "c" : 4
    }
    ...
    "sun" : {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2,
        "c" : 3
    }
}
```

Field names are the same this is Repeated field value
It is a structure in which only the key is changed. 
How do you serialize this type of JSON?
I want to make an object and float it in my UI

mon, tue, wed, ... sun, do I really need to create a class?

I want to easily import and write data for each day of the week

Comment: This question could use some clarification. What exactly are you having trouble doing?

Comment: you want to create model file based on this JSON or What you really looking for

Comment: @Vasanth Vadivel 
you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this website is what you're looking for:
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

You simply paste your json (usually the response coming from an API) and it creates a class in dart for that json. so then, you can use it like:

```
MyJsonClass classResponse = MyJsonClass.fromJson(apiResponse);
```

And access its parameters like this:

```
print(classResponse.mon.a) // output: 3
```

generated code used:

```
class Days {
  Mon mon;
  Mon tue;
  Mon wed;
  Mon sun;

  Days({this.mon, this.tue, this.wed, this.sun});

  Days.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    mon = json['mon'] != null ? new Mon.fromJson(json['mon']) : null;
    tue = json['tue'] != null ? new Mon.fromJson(json['tue']) : null;
    wed = json['wed'] != null ? new Mon.fromJson(json['wed']) : null;
    sun = json['sun'] != null ? new Mon.fromJson(json['sun']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.mon != null) {
      data['mon'] = this.mon.toJson();
    }
    if (this.tue != null) {
      data['tue'] = this.tue.toJson();
    }
    if (this.wed != null) {
      data['wed'] = this.wed.toJson();
    }
    if (this.sun != null) {
      data['sun'] = this.sun.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Mon {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  Mon({this.a, this.b, this.c});

  Mon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    a = json['a'];
    b = json['b'];
    c = json['c'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['a'] = this.a;
    data['b'] = this.b;
    data['c'] = this.c;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using that website, you need to create a class for each day of the week. 
So isn't the code too messy? Is there any way?

Comment: actually it's not creating a class for each day. it's creating an instance of a class Mon in my case. I updated my answer with a generated code from there.

Comment: Thanks for giving a good answer to a bad question